# SPARQL Distinct pairs

Tags: sparql, sesame

I've got a table, where there are documents with identical authors. I need to get the distinct pairs of documents. I did the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?d1 ?d2  WHERE {
?d1 myns:creator ?x.
?d2 myns:creator ?y.
FILTER (?x=?y && ?d1!=?d2).
}
GROUP BY ?d1 ?d2
```

But for this both `DOC1, DOC2` and `DOC2, DOC1` are in the result. I need to get rid of one of the pairs.
Here is the whole triples database:

```
@prefix xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> . 
@prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix myns: <http://my.local.namespace#> .

_:doc1 rdf:type myns:Document.
_:doc1 myns:creator _:Pete.
_:doc1 myns:year "2000"^^xsd:integer.
_:doc1 myns:publisher _:p1.

_:doc2 rdf:type myns:Document.
_:doc2 myns:creator _:John.
_:doc2 myns:year "2004"^^xsd:integer.
_:doc2 myns:publisher _:p2.


_:doc3 rdf:type myns:Document.
_:doc3 myns:creator _:Pete.
_:doc3 myns:publisher _:p3.

_:doc4 rdf:type myns:Document.
_:doc4 myns:creator _:Bob.
_:doc4 myns:year "2010"^^xsd:integer.
_:doc4 myns:publisher _:p2.

_:Pete rdf:type myns:Person.
_:Pete myns:knows _:Bob.
_:Pete myns:knows _:John .

_:John rdf:type myns:Person.
_:John myns:age "29"^^xsd:integer.
_:John myns:knows _:Bob.

_:Bob rdf:type myns:Person.
_:Bob myns:age "35"^^xsd:integer.
```

The result, that I am getting, after executing query is:

```
D1  D2
_:891f1e98-b411-4e54-9533-18d530f09c6ddoc1  _:891f1e98-b411-4e54-9533-18d530f09c6ddoc3
_:891f1e98-b411-4e54-9533-18d530f09c6ddoc3  _:891f1e98-b411-4e54-9533-18d530f09c6ddoc1
```

As it is noticeable, technically  both pairs are same. I junst need distinct one (i.e. one of them is enough). I am not sure about enviromental characteristics. But there is Sesame framework

Comment: Judging from your comments on my answer, your question is missing essential information. You need to show a [complete, minimal, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including a minimal sample of the _actual_ data you're executing this on (something we can copy-paste to put into a triplestore), the output you _expect_ to get, and the output you're actually getting. It would also help tremendously if you tell us which software (which SPARQL engine, which database, which programming language, etc) you're using.

Comment: thank you, much clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work in *some* systems:

```
SELECT ?d1 ?d2  WHERE {
  ?d1 myns:creator ?x.
  ?d2 myns:creator ?y.
  FILTER (?x=?y && STR(IRI(?d1)) < STR(IRI(?d2))).
}
```

`?d1` and `?d2` are going to be blank nodes.  But blank nodes are blank.
So to provide the ordering for `<`, we need some kind of query-wide label or value associated with each one.

Your data does not have any distinguishing triples for each person.It would be better to put real names in the data:

```
_:Pete rdfs:label "Pete" .
```

Even better, use the [FOAF](http://www.foaf-project.org/) vocabulary.

Some systems allow blank nodes in `IRI()` - technically it's an extension of the SPARQL specification.  You can then take the `STR` form and compare.  that works on your data for me (Apache Jena) - You don't say which RDF system you are using.

The best solution is put distinguishing information into the data.

Comment: here is the engine http://kilda.informatik.uni-freiburg.de:8080/openrdf-workbench/repositories/pubs/query

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a little trick: turn the `!=` into a `<` (or `>`), and convert the values to strings, so you can do lexical comparisons:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?d1 ?d2  WHERE {
?d1 myns:creator ?x.
?d2 myns:creator ?y.
FILTER (?x=?y && STR(?d1) < STR(?d2)).
}
GROUP BY ?d1 ?d2
```

This works on the idea that for any pair of identifiers that are not equal, one identifier is always greater than the other (by lexical ordering). So of any two pairs, only one will actually be selected.

**Update** so now that you've shown your data, we can see that the problem is that you are not using IRIs to distinguish your documents, but use blank nodes. The above query does not work because according to the SPARQL standard, blank nodes are unordered (so directly comparing via `<` does not work), and moreover, the `STR` function is defined to only operate on literals or IRIs, not on blank nodes.

The best solution is to change your data, and make sure that you use proper IRIs, because regardless of whether you can somehow make this query work on this data, the result would be almost useless: blank nodes have no meaning outside their local scope, so the document identifiers that your query returns can not really be reused; for example, you would not be able to do a SPARQL query that gets any properties specifically for the document `_:doc1` (although to be fair Sesame has a workaround for this in the API).

A very simple way to change your blank nodes to IRIs, by the way, is to replace all occurrences of `_:` in your turtle file with `myns:`.

Comment: Ah, you may need to explicitly convert to string first. Edited.

Comment: Then you need to provide a lot of additional details about your setup and what your actual data looks like.